# Header DIV Going Behind Sidebar Div

Tags: html, css, z-index

As the title says, I have started off by making my sidebar which I am finished with for now, but when I add my header no matter what positive I give either of them, the header `div` is either behind or sitting on top of the sidebar `div`.

Problem screenshot:
[image: Problem screenshot]

Any input on this is highly appreciated.

```css
body{
    background-color: #f1f6f6;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#sidebar{
    background-color: #212528;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav{
    color: #888888;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#nav li:hover {
    background:#333;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}

.link{
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 20%;
}

#searchbar{
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    text-align: right;
}

#searchbar input{
    max-width: 95%;
}

#header{
    position: ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lakeside Books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="masterstyle.css">
    <meta name="viewsize" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <nav id="nav">
            <h3 style="text-align: center">Welcome To<br>Lakeside Books</h3>
            <div id="searchbar">
                <form action="http://www.example.com/search.php">
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="....Search Book Title"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="link">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="link">
                        Categories
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="link">
                        Bestsellers
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="link">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Lakeside Books</h1>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to fix it. It depends on what are you trying to do. For example, the #header is now 100% of the available width - the element who wraps it (because it's the default of a block element (div in this case) and you didn't set it other way) when the #sidebar is about 20% of the available width and in `position: fixed;` so 20% of your #header will stay under the #sidebar like this.

For example, you can set the #header to `width: 80%;` at most and stick it to the right (the opposite side).

*you don't have to use position fixed or absolute, you can use "float" to both of the elements (one left and the other right) so they will not "rise above" other outside elements. Don't forget to set block element to `clear: both;` after the elements who use "float" because it will "break" the wrapper element. So, in this case set it for the #wrapper.
(you can set `overflow: hidden`; to the #wrapper instead, but it will hide everything out side the element - in case you are trying to use a trick or something...

Comment: Thank you for that, didn't think of it at all!

Answer (score 0):

An element with `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;` is getting detached from the initial flow of the page and stays above it.

If several elements have their `position: fixed;` the first one declared in your HTML will be below, and the last one above, unless you specify it with the CSS property `z-index`.

In your case, as your sidebar has `width: 20%;` you could for eventually give a `margin-left: 20%;` to your body.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you sidebar is fixed and the rest is default.

The most simple fix (and one of several possibilities) would be to add `margin-left: X;` to the `header`, or if the sidebar is static, you may consider adding it to the `body` in the css.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Puddster/jcky1w0b/) for a potential solution.

Further reading on how different CSS positions interact with each other can be found [here](http://learnlayout.com/position-example.html).